# How to set $interval for 24 hours in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

I need to call a service repeatedly with a delay of 24 hours.
I have set `$interval` for 24 hours delay in my code using the below code

```
self.synInterval = self.$interval(self.checkAppStatus, 24 * 60 * 60000);
```

It is working fine and calling the service if delay is 2 hours .ie

```
self.synInterval = self.$interval(self.checkAppStatus, 2 * 60 * 60000);
```

But it is not working if it is 24 hours.

Comment: Hello @Roshni, May [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) helps you.

Comment: How you can make cronjob using front-end ?

Comment: Server side is updating at every 24 hours . I need to update that change in front-end.

Comment: Is your client-side application active for 24 hours or more? How do you check if it is working or not?

Comment: yes.. it is active.